# Multiple similar CRUD methods with Hibernate and Repository Pattern?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, repository-pattern

With a Repository Design Pattern (of what I've understood so far) you have a repository for each business model. All these repositories implements a IRepository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
   boolean add(T item);
   boolean update(T item);
   boolean remove(T item);
   List<T> query(Specification specification);
}
```

With Hibernate, I save new records this way:

```
try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(mappedObject);
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {

        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Wouldn't each repository have basically duplicates of the add method? Wouldn't it then be better to make a Repository class with an already defined add method etc.?

Comment: when you use some Repository, you are using some implementation which receives generic values, then you don't need to implement all those methods, are common for all classes which use the repository interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you create an `AbstractRepository` implementation that implements your `IRepository` interface for common methods that are shared and then extend your business repository implementations from the abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> implements IRepository<T> {
  @Override
  public T add(T object) {
    Session session = openSession();
    try {
      session.getTransaction().begin();
      session.save( object );
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      return object;
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
      if ( session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE ) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
      }
      throw e;
    }
    finally {
      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Upon reviewing my system, there are classes that need to map the business objects to POJO differently. But all of them would still need to call the add method, is it a bad design to let all the repository extending from `AbsRepo<T>` to have an add() which maps the business object and calls on `super.add("mappedObject")` ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you find you have the need to map from a POJO to your entity type for `#add()`, I suspect you'll have a need for the inverse perhaps with find like methods too.  Why not simply have a separate class that handles the transformation and invoke that in the tier of code that calls add rather than adding that at the db tier?